# How to return the first row of my SQLite Table in Eclipse

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have inserted into my Android Eclipse project an SQLite Table to store some data and I want to return the first row of my SQLite Table.

My database class is DataBaseHandler.java

```java
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


    public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "My_SQLite_Database.db";

    //constructor for this class
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating the Table when the class is executed    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "My_SQLite_Database" + "("
                + "Image_ID" + " TEXT,"
                + "Image" + " TEXT," + "Title" + " TEXT," + "Info" + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);//executing the create table query
    }

    //for inserting data into this table write the following method
      public void addData(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Image_ID", field1); 
        values.put("Image", field2); 
        values.put("Title", field3); 
        values.put("Info",  field4); 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert("My_SQLite_Database", null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DataBaseHandler.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "My_SQLite_Database");
            onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I initialize my SQLite Table(having 4 columns and 4 rows) in my onCreate

```java
DataBaseHandler db;
        db = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());//Your table is created now

        db.addData("d1e14b170ff4418693fd0ceb4987adda","string2","string3","string4");
        db.addData("6102a756d92e40d392a4e0ebcb53edb5", "string6", "string7","string8");
        db.addData("9d78a74cf93e479f8e08b47072264b66", "string10", "string11","string12");
        db.addData("482f894ae06746439d86f8e5efa26914", "string14", "string15","string16");
```

Now I want in  onResume of my MainActivity to return the first row of my SQLite Table at a specific point of my code.What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this StackOverflow question to get started in the right direction - [Get first row data if exist in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111313/get-first-row-data-if-exist-in-sqlite)

Comment: ... and do a favour to yourself: **avoid useless string concatenations** (only the useless ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-->Problem solved.It works like a charm and retrieves a specific SQLite row<--

I inserted a method named getContact in DataBaseHandler.java to retrieve a specific row and I called it my MainActivity.

```
// ---retrieves a particular contact, written in DataBaseHandler---
    public Cursor getContact(String rowId) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_IMAGEID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_INFO }, KEY_IMAGEID + " LIKE '"
                + rowId + "'", null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {
                Log.e("GetContact", "cursor empty for " + KEY_IMAGEID + "=\""
                        + rowId + "\"");

            }

        } else
            Log.e("GetContact", "cursor null");
        return mCursor;
    }
```

//Main Activity call of getContact method

```
    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Image_ID:" + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Title:" + c.getString(1)
                            + "\n" + "Info:" + c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

DataBaseHandler db;
        db = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());// Your table is
                                                            // created now

        db.open();

        Cursor c = db.getContact("24");
        System.out.println("Cursor size " + c.getCount());
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            DisplayContact(c); // edo kalei ti methodo DisplayContact pou
                                // tiponei tin
                                // 2i grammi tou SQLite Table
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
        }
```